# GumROS log4cxx compilation problem

Tags: cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install GumROS to my Overo Fire. I have followed the tutorial on the ROS wiki[1]. Before compiling ROS, I need to compile and install patched version of log4cxx. I got source then configure it with:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/gumros \
            --host=arm-linux \
            --with-apr=/opt/gumros \
            --with-apr-util=/opt/gumros \
            ac_cv_file__dev_zero=yes \
            ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes \
            apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork=no \
            apr_cv_process_shared_works=no \
            apr_cv_mutex_robust_shared=no \
            ac_cv_sizeof_struct_iovec=8
```

and then i have managed to make install. Everything was fine up to this point. But while i was trying "sudo make install", i got following error:

```
libtool: install: warning: relinking `liblog4cxx.la'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: install: error: relink `liblog4cxx.la' with the above command before installing it
make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I especially do not understand the error:

~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

PS: GCC v4.3.3 (which: ~/overo-oe/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/armv7a/bin/gcc)

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9818/gumros-log4cxx-compilation-problem/) by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-04-27**:
i cannot figure out how to solve this issue. I continued with installing ubuntu on my overo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Libtool is relinking when doing the install step. Ive not had any other toolchain I've tried with log4cxx, but the angstrom one built from open-embedded does. Oddly enough, it only does it for log4cxx as well, not apr_util, so it maybe a problem with its linking on c++ targets (apr_util is c).

The symptom: when relinking in the install step it links differently than it did in the build step - the notable problem is that it adds -L/usr/lib to the library search path (you should be able to see this a little above the error message), which means it brings the wrong format libraries to the table.

This seems to be a recent common problem with openembedded and their toolchains, see [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool-patches/2011-01/msg00026.html) for details. Lots of other links if you google about it too.

I'm currently looking to see if there's a workaround I can put in [eros_log4cxx](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_log4cxx) and also testing to see if the more recent versions of openembedded versions have fixed this problem (I read they addressed it in head).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-02**:
Quick update : just built a toolchain targeted for the beagleboard via open embedded, and it has no problem when relinking. Who builds your toolchain?